# Automatically add traces based on dataframe

Tags: python, plotly, data-science

I'm trying to use Plotly Scatter to make monthly balance of each branch.
Below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'BAS_DT': ['202101','202102','202103','202104','202105','202106',
               '202101','202102','202103','202104','202105','202106',
               '202101','202102','202103','202104','202105','202106'],
    'BR_CD': ['001','001','001','001','001','001',
              '100','100','100','100','100','100',
              '101','101','101','101','101','101'],
    'BAL':[1100,1150,950,1020,999,1025,
           1200,1050,950,1000,950,1075,
           1080,1115,990,898,915,1100]})

df1 = df1.pivot_table(index='BAS_DT', columns='BR_CD', values='BAL').reset_index()
df1.head()

# df1
BR_CD   BAS_DT  001 100 101
0   202101  1100    1200    1200
1   202102  1150    1050    1050
2   202103  950 950 950
3   202104  1020    1000    1000
4   202105  999 950 950
5   202106  1025    1025    1025

fig=go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=df1['BAS_DT'],
    y=df1['001'],
    name="001",
    text=df1['001'],
    mode='lines+markers+text',
    textposition='top center',
    line_shape='spline'))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=df1['BAS_DT'],
    y=df1['100'],
    name="100",
    text=df1['100'],
    mode='lines+markers+text',
    textposition='top center',
    line_shape='spline'))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=df1['BAS_DT'],
    y=df1['101'],
    name="101",
    text=df1['101'],
    mode='lines+markers+text',
    textposition='top center',
    line_shape='spline'))

fig.show()
```

Fig show as below:
[image]

But my problem is that I will have to add new traces manually if new branches appear. I want to ask is there any way to automatically add new traces based on input dataframe?

Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iteratively add the traces by looping through the columns you want to use in df1. In this example case you want all the columns that come after column index 0 (BAS_DT) or `df1.columns[1:]`

```
fig=go.Figure()

for col in df1.columns[1:]:
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=df1['BAS_DT'],
        y=df1[col],
        name=col,
        text=df1[col],
        mode='lines+markers+text',
        textposition='top center',
        line_shape='spline'))

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it's worked. Really appreciate.

Comment: @hoatran no, problem and good luck with your project.